# Call Multiple Sidebars at once

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I have multiple sidebars registered for my site's footer, called `footer-1`, `footer-2`, and `footer-3`. It will be a 3 column layout in my footer. What is the best way to call these 3 sidebars? Should I check if all 3 `is_active_sidebar()` then register them? Or is there a better way to so so?

Comment: You register the sidebars irregardless, since you can have an empty sidebar, `is_active_sidebar()` simply checks if a sidebar has widgets.

Comment: you could check how it is done in Twenty Eleven; there is some related code in sidebar-footer.php and functions.php